# URL for images outside jar file with java Fx

Tags: java, jar, javafx

In Java FX, I declared my image's location in jxml file with Image tag.

```
<Image url="@../images/myImage.png" />
```

This works well when the images folder is stored inside the project, and later on exported together with codes in a jar file. Yet I want to load images dynamically. For examples, I will put the exported jar file and the images folder in a same directory. Then the jar file will use image from the images folder. The problem is no matter how I try to change the url, the jar file can't load images from the external images folder. Can someone show me where were I wrong?

- Location of my fxml:
  C:/myproject/project/application/gui/MainMenu.fxml
- Location of my images folder: C:/myproject/images
- Location of my exported jar: C:/myproject

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add the location of fxml and the location of the image?

Comment: Hi @ItachiUchiha I added locations as you asked

Comment: Is `project/application/gui` your package name?

Comment: yes they are also the packages' names

Comment: Have you tried `../../../images/myImage.png`.

Comment: I just tried, didnt work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71499/discussion-between-itachiuchiha-and-xitrum).